# find_or_create_by on intermediate table in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby, associations, ruby-on-rails-2

I have 2 tables , related to a third table as follows.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :B, :through => :AB
  has_many :AB
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :A, :through => :AB
  has_many :AB
end

class AB < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :B,
  belongs_to :A
end
```

I want to be able to insert into the intermediate table(AB), using find_or_create.But find_or_create doesnot work on AB. How can I do it, other than finding and creating seperately ??

PS: I dont want to use has_and_belongs_to_many because that doesnot create the intermediate model and i want to insert into the intermediate table without creating any extra rows in  the end tables, A and B.

Some suggestions please??

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

`find_or_create_by` has been added in rails 4. You can write it by yourself (should go to initializers):

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by(params)
    scoped.where(params).limit(1).first
  end

  def self.find_or_create_by(params)
    find_by(params) || create(params)
  end
end
```